# Spring boot jackson auto configuration linkage error wildfly

Tags: jboss, jackson, spring-boot, wildfly

A.war -> Is a simple spring boot REST app using version 1.2.6.RELEASE ( internally using spring 4.1.7 RELEASE, jackson 2.4.6 )

B.jar -> Is a wildfly9 shared module (stored in wildfly/modules) which is packaged using maven shaded plugin containing spring framework (without spring boot meaning using the old way of adding spring projects dependencies) and jackson classes of same version as above. (Its shaded because non-spring and non-container projects can just add this jar in their class-path and use it - it works)

A.war has maven dependency `scope <provided> on B.jar` and has jboss-deployment-structure.xml with  `<dependencies> <module name = "B"> </dependencies>`
A.war deployment fails with below error.

**Note: A.war deploys perfectly fine when i remove B.jar jboss dependency. So adding B.jar is causing this issue. And If i don't use spring boot in A.war (meaning if i use simple spring webmvc and context dependencies directly) with B.jar jboss dependency, A.war deploys perfectly too**

Can anyone explain me what the error below says and how can i investigate more ?

As far as my understanding on wildlfy classloading, A.war and B.jar should be loaded in different module class loaders, Is A.war complaining about jackson classes of B.jar here in the error ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method
 "org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;"
 the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class,
 org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration,
 and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class,
 org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder,
 have different Class objects for the type der used in the signature
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.configureModules(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:259)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.jacksonObjectMapperBuilder(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:186)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b993caa0.CGLIB$jacksonObjectMapperBuilder$1()
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b993caa0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5262bf2.invoke()
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b993caa0.jacksonObjectMapperBuilder()
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ... 108 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating more jboss classloading behavior, jackson classes inside  B.jar are conflicting with same jackson classes from jboss restesay module.
so after excluding them in jboss-deployment-structure.xml as below this problem is fixed..

```
<exclusions>
     <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/> 
     <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider"/> 
</exclusions>
```